# How to ensure that header request are sent when using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to call a RESTful API in my Android app using Volley. The API requires that the user get authenticated using a public key and a hash that will be sent via the http header.

When I try to do send a POST request with the headers of the public key and the hash, I find that the header is not appended / received by the server and I get Volley error - BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400

This is the method that i am trying to use to send the header request with the request parameters using JSON.

```
 HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                params.put("email", email.getText().toString());
                params.put("password", password.getText().toString());

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

                RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
                JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(ApplicationConstants.url_sign_in, new JSONObject
                        (params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse") ;
                            error = response.getBoolean(TAG_ERROR);
                            message = response.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message + " value of error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            pDialog.cancel();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"onErrorResponse()") ;
                        pDialog.cancel();
                        NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                        if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                            // HTTP Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put(ApplicationConstants.publicKey, "Yahoo");
                        headers.put(ApplicationConstants.hash, "Google");
                        Log.d(TAG,"getHeaders()") ;
                        return headers;
                    }

                };

                requestQueue.add(request);
```

ApplicationConstants class

```
public interface ApplicationConstants {

//String ip = "10.0.3.2";
String ip = "192.168.100.2";
String publicKey = "pskPublicKey";
String hash = "pskPublicKey";
```

[image: As you can see I supplied the public key and the hash in postman and I also sent data in the header from android but it is not being received in the server]

If I try this with only the request parameters it works but when when i try to send a header request it fails to send the header request.

As you can see in the pic I supplied the public key and the hash in postman and I also sent data in the header from android but it is not being received in the server

Answer (score 0):

400 means a Bad Request to the server. Maybe the headers are wrong. 
You could try adding the `Content-Type=application/json` header as follows

```
 header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

If this doesn't work then you should try the request in the [REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and see if it works with the given headers. Make sure the request works fine on the rest client before trying to break your head in Android.

Comment: It does work in the REST client I check it using post man. I also tired 'header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");'

Comment: If you dont mind, can you attach a screenshot of the postman rest client request that works? I can then compare the params/headers that you're sending there vs the android code.

Comment: Are you sure the constants `ApplicationConstants.publicKey` and `ApplicationConstants.hash` correspond to "pskPublicKey" and "pskPrivateKey" respectively?

Comment: And what is the value of `ApplicationConstants.url_sign_in`?

Comment: that is the value of the url. String url_sign_in = "http://"+ip+"/task_manager/v1/login";

Answer (score 0):

override your `getBodyContentType` method

```
public String getBodyContentType()
    {
        return "application/json";
    }
```